# How to do socket programming in android

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

I want to create the android application in which i send the data from the android device to desktop application using wifi devices. I am not confirmed but i think that it can be possible with the socket programming. so please help me to give guidence for how to send data from android device to desktop using WIFI.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's possible to use standard java socket in android (using javax.net.SocketFactory).
I'm not very experimented with java socket, but there is some documentation about that when searching it in google.

Answer (score 3):

here are some examples of socket programming in android, hope they help.

UDP: http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=280

TCP: http://www.anddev.org/general-f3/socket-programming-t325.html#wrap